# Kanban story assignment

Tags: kanban

We are starting to use Kanban and my boss just asked me a question, as one of two people with prior Kanban experience within the group, that I don't really know how to answer.

My previous experience and training with Kanban had developers pulling stories in from the backlog by priority, in our case that was the topmost card.  However, my boss would like certain stories to go to the developers that have domain knowledge for particular areas.  For example, let's say Joe has the most experience in working with Contracts and a contract story comes onto the board.  He would like Joe to be the one to work on that particular story.

This, to me, feels a little "off" and could lead to some developers having significant extra work due to having worked in any given area of functionality.  My previous experience with Kanban worked under the assumption that any developer should be able to pick up the next card and figure out what to do and that this practice would eventually eliminate any single functionality area experts and level out developer expertise over time.  However, I can also see how using subject matter experts can help move a story through the process faster.

What is the most "Kanban" way of handling priority vs. expertise when it comes to pulling in the next story?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every system I've ever worked with allows a little bit of developer-level of prioritization. If the next card has the absolute (top-down driven) priority, then you have to pick that card. Mostly, though, I tend to work in places where "these next 6 cards are up, pick the one you like". This gives the developer a little bit of room for type of work he or she prefers. Plus, it gives the developers a greater sense of ownership since they did get to pick (to some extent) the work they were doing.

Regarding your example, it's a little off base. In an ideal world any developer should be able to pick up any card. In reality, this isn't always true. If I give this project to Jim, it might take 2 days. If I give it to not-Jim, it make take all week. This is a sign! What information sharing is missing? How do you get the other developers to understand the Contracts component as well as Jim?

If the priority is a little bit gray, this stuff tends to work itself out. All the other developers know that Jim can handle the Contracts stuff. However, if Jim has no capacity, then someone else must take up the challenge. Kanban is supposed to alert you to blocked stories.

Comment: Sorry, I had introduced a typo in the example.  I've fixed it now.  I meant to say that they would like to assign cards to those who have the most experience in that area.

Comment: Kanban is pull, not push. Managers don't *assign* work. Developers take work from the pile. If someone else wants to work on a feature, that should be allowed - even encouraged.

Comment: That's exactly what I was struggling with.  My experience was that devs pull stories onto the board.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kanban is great for visualizing work flow, limiting WIP, and exposing bottle necks.

Henrik Kniberg has a great book, 'Lean from the Trenches'.  He talks through many techniques he has used in real world examples.  He described one approach to having avatars (that represent developers) that can be placed over task to show who is working on what.

One idea for your situation, would be to use this avatar approach to pre-assigning who should work on a task in the buffer leading into development.

If those pre-assigned tasks are not causing bottlenecks and flow is natural, everything is good.  If they are causing bottlenecks early in your flow, you have a problem, but now you have an easy way to visualize and see that it is the pre-assigning that is causing your bottle neck!

Answer (score 0):

A Kanban system shall display the real process. If the manager is assigning stories to developer then the system should reflect that. This can be done in several ways, you could have a specific item for developer X or you can write the developers name on the card. Another option is to have one swim-lane for each developer.

However, all of this is probably not good from a "global" perspective. You should share your Kanban data with your boss. What are your lead-times, what is your throughput etc? Then you should invite the boss to the process improvment meeting. How are we going to improve our figures? Hopefully he sees that Joe probably will be a bottleneck if he is assigning tasks directly to him. Teach him Littles Law, teach him about bottlenecks and Lean in general.

Don't forget to make your policies explicit, that is, it should be written on the wall how your prioritzation policy looks like. Good luck!